# Jqgrid xml data population

Tags: jqgrid

I have an arraylist with multiple arraylists of different sizes in it. I need to populate this data in jqgrid which accepts xml input. What can be done to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the Wiki on data source format?

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_string

Here's the format for XML

```
<invoices> 
   <request>true</request> 
   ... 
   <currentpage>1</currentpage>
   <totalpages>10</totalpages>
   <totalrecords>20</totalrecords>
   <result> 
      <invoice> 
         <asin>12345</asin>
         <invoiceno>data1</invoiceno>
         <invoicedate>data2</invoicedate> 
         <invoiceamount>data3</invoiceamount> 
         <invoicetax>data4</invoicetax> 
         <invoicetotal>data5</invoicetotal> 
         <notes>data6</notes> 
      </invoice> 
      ... 
   </result> 
</invoices>
```